# Captioning video from mobile

Tags: applications, youtube

I have a Youtube account with videos uploaded. I would like to caption them. I tried to google how, but I found either "go to video manager" (which I canmot find on the android apl) or a suggestion for Caption Tube, which is not on Play Store, and the website linked to in the page that suggested this gives a loading error. So is there a way to caption youtube videos from the app, or from some other Android app? If there is, which is it?

Comment: YouTube creator studio app?

Comment: @DanBrown just downloaded that from Play Store, cannot find anythig about captions of subs in it.

Comment: Then you can either do it through Chrome (May need 'request desktop site') or do it on a desktop (as intended.

Comment: @DanBrown I started with Chrome on mobile and finished with Firefox on Computer since the video only loaded partially. Other than thay, things worked out perfectly fine on mobile. Would you convert that comment to an answer? PS The reason I wanted to use my mobile is ghat I'm permanently logged in to my Uni email on my computer and logging in to Youtube would have forced a logout and then a login.

Comment: Also, I guess any mobile browser will do fine with the desktop site. Firefox sure seems to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, You can modify the Captions by opening the video in chrome (or Firefox), ticking 'request desktop site' in their menus, and edit as normal.